# Indy http server questions

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using indy's http server for a project so i have a few questions:

- Does the event OnConnect get's executed even if one connects on a separate thread?
- Can i update the vcl from the event OnConnect
- If MaxNumberConnections is
  set to 0 what does it exactly mean ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1. Does the event OnConnect get's executed in a separate thread ?***

Yes, the event will get fired as the other events do, even if you are running in a separate thread. The question remains to be answered by you is why. The [`TIdTCPServer`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdTCPServer.html) already uses multithreading thus
 it can be used in a main thread context (on a form).

---

***2. Can I update the VCL from the OnConnect event ?***

Yes, but you will have to use some GUI synchronization practice, such as [`Synchronize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) method or e.g. message posting from the separated worker thread to your main one.

---

***3. If MaxNumberConnections is set to 0 what does it exactly mean ?***

Zero value assigned to the [`MaxConnections`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdCustomTCPServer_MaxConnections.html) means there is no limit of connections at one time.